# Say 'you are pretty' to a person

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

**Context**

Say A meets B some days ago and wants to say him/her that she is pretty, not as a declaration of love but as a way to start a conversation.  What is the proper way to say it?

**Example**

> A: Hello
>
> B: Hi 'nice lady/darling/pretty woman/...'

**Question**

I can't find the right word. What's the proper way to say to a girl that she is pretty in a message?

Comment: First, in English, "nice" usually refers to personality, and "pretty" refers to physical appearance, so it's not clear which you're trying to refer to here. Second, at least in modern American culture, it's usually inappropriate to comment on a woman's appearance unless you're either close friends or are trying to flirt with them. If you do want to express appreciation for a previous conversation, you'd say something like, "Hi [name], it was great talking with you the other day!"

Comment: @CanadianYankee that's fine, but that's why I am asking sr. Not every culture is american/english and I supposed there was a translation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English language usage.

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 2):

These all look very odd and awkward.

If I had met someone a couple of days ago, and I wasn't romantically interested in them I wouldn't be saying that they are pretty at all. It sounds like a flirt at best, and very creepy at worst

However, if I knew someone better, and knew that they wouldn't take my comment the wrong way, I might say,

> Hi, you're looking good today.

If they were actually looking especially good that day.

If this is a text message, I wouldn't use any similar expression. It's too creepy.

Comment: uhmm but thats not the way I mean...Maybe you can ask in a comment?

Comment: There isn't a proper way to say it.  So don't say it.